# How to manage the java scripts references between different pages and needs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

Let's say I have couple of web pages where a single datepicker is used.
In addition, I have another web page where I need 3 datepickers on the same page.

So how do I manage the java script id reference? Should I have single script in `_layout.xml` with something like this?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
            $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

And all pages (besides the multiple) will have :

```
 <div id="datepicker1"></div>
```

and the multiple will have:

```
 <div id="datepicker1"></div>
 <div id="datepicker2"></div>
 <div id="datepicker3"></div>
```

I come from OO programming and something doesn't fit here. What are the conventions in web\js world to this common use case?

**Edit: the mmultiple datepicker page script has different settings...**

Comment: It's possible to grab multiple IDs in jQuery with `$('[id^="datepicker"]').datepicker()`, but as has been noted below, the *best* solution is a common class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If they all use exactly the same settings, use a class:

```
<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

then

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

That will handle everything with the class `datepicker` on it, no matter how many there are (one, three, ten thousand [though that might make the page incredibly slow]).

If they need different settings then you'll need to stick with IDs, and initialise them all individually, as you've shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers in this thread. I have decided to go with common class to all and for multiple (which has different settings) I'll create its own thing. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class instead of an ID if they are all going to initializate the plugin in the same way:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
}); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="datepicker"></div>
<div class="datepicker"></div>
<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: This is what I do too. But here is what I don't like about it: ReSharper and Visual Studio warn me that the class is not defined anywhere. I could always put extra markup in my CSS, but that seems like the exact wrong answer to me. Has anyone else solved this problem?

Comment: @CharlieKilian It's a warning, not an error, so feel free to ignore it; as far as I'm aware/concerned using classes explicitly for identifying elements (i.e. the class has no attached styling) is a standard practice.

Comment: @CharlieKilian I don't see any problem with it. Those warnings aren't suppose to be there. This is technically the good way to do it.

Comment: Agree with you both. I hate ignoring warnings, is the only thing. It leads to a bad mindset. But thank you both for your feedback. Good to know I'm not the only one.

Comment: @CharlieKilian are you saying that sometimes the `.datepicker` won't be in the HTML markup while the javasript calling it will?

Comment: @Alvaro no, I'm saying that if you add `class="datepicker"` to your markup, you'll get a warning that the class isn't defined in CSS. The warning is true, but the situation is common, as you pointed out above. The best answer is probably to figure out a way to turn off the single broken warning.

Comment: @CharlieKilian yeah that doesn't make sense. Classes can and should be used as well for javascript without any need to be linked to any stylesheet.